# textView.SetText working only when text is long

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, settext

For some odd reason the setText only works when the text is above 600+ chars...
I get the text from my database.

Here is the **code**

```
private void renderViewDescription() {
    // reference

    final TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_tour_detail_overview_text);
    // content
    Log.d("Overview: ",mTour.getOverview()); //Text is always ok
    descriptionTextView.setText(mTour.getOverview());
}
```

**XML**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/global_spacing_xxs"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Headline"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Overview" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/dividerHorizontal" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_tour_detail_overview_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/global_spacing_xxs"
            android:text="Body"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/global_text_secondary"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/dividerHorizontal" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[When text has many chars it works...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKXe.jpg)

[image]

[When it's  below 500 - 600 it doesn't...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J52KG.jpg)

[image]

Comment: try to use **ScrollView** also

Comment: post screen shot when text is less

Comment: `mTour.getOverview()` is string value?

Comment: @MounirElfassi there is no exception. The texview is just empty... Check out the foto I uploaded "When it's below 500-600 it doesn't". That's the only thing that happens

Comment: @SohailZahid yeah it's just a string.

Comment: Is `mTour.getOverview()` returning characters less then 600?? have you got  them in Log??

Comment: @jankigadhiya I did, it's in the text. It works fine. The whole text get shown without any problem.

Comment: @Alexander This XML its included in another xml which has a scroll view.

Comment: @AresProductions Can you please show me your TextAppearance TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1 ?

Comment: I am talking about **less then 600 words**. are u getting log or Toast or anything that proves that.?? It may be possible that. your `mTour.getOverview()` is not returning anything.. simply blank..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya Log.d("Overview: ",mTour.getOverview()); always shows the text as it is. No matter if its more or less than 600 chars. So getOverview works fine. It returns the string as it should.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer   
<style name="TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
  <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/global_text_size_body_1</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
 </style>

Comment: @AresProductions May be your view is overlapping the body `Text View` try by removing the `View`. **Remove** the `View` which is **between** both `Text Views`. It's overlapping your body text.

Comment: The wrap_content seems to ignore the content, try to set it to match_parent just to see if the text is in it, maybe you style has something wrong.

Comment: Try removing textAppearance attribute for test and see if you are getting output.

Comment: @jaydroider You are right!!! When I removed the <View/> between the Headline and the Body  the small text appeared!

Comment: @AresProductions Have you get it Worked ?

Comment: @jaydroider Yeah now the small text works too! But is the a way to keep the view? Cause it for UI enchantment.

And also any idea why this happens when the text is smaller?

Comment: @AresProductions I am adding this as an answer please accept it. Can you tell me what is the Exact purpose to add View their in between both `Text Views` ?

Comment: @jaydroider Actually I just set android:layout_height="1dp" on the View and now everything works as it should.

Comment: @jaydroider I added it just for the sake of beauty. :P

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to remove the `View` from your `Layout` which is between both `Text Views` because it is overlapping your Body Text.
>
> Also if you set `android:layout_height="1dp"` in your `View` here then it will work.

**Refer this only.**

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Overview"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <!--<View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/dividerHorizontal" />-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_tour_detail_overview_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="OverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewOverviewO"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is helpful to you thanks :) check mark as correct on **Left** on the answer.